# I am using pig version .8 , How to extract specific elements of xml by using XPath() ?. I tried with multiple ways but couldn't get.Please suggest

Tags: hadoop, xpath

```
<CATALOG>
<BOOK>
<TITLE>Hadoop Defnitive Guide</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Tom White</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CLOUDERA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>24.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2012</YEAR>
</BOOK>
</CATALOG>
```

This is xml i am using.

I want to extract only TITLE and COMPANY elements.Is there any way to extract them by using Regex or XPath();

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is format your XML like so:

```
    <CATALOG> 
      <BOOK> 
        <TITLE>Hadoop Defnitive Guide</TITLE>  
        <AUTHOR>Tom White</AUTHOR>  
        <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>  
        <COMPANY>CLOUDERA</COMPANY>  
        <PRICE>24.90</PRICE>  
        <YEAR>2012</YEAR> 
      </BOOK> 
    </CATALOG>
```

Then you can extract those elements like so:

```
/CATALOG/BOOK/*[self::title or self::company]
```

More about axes you can find here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Are you saying that it is necessary to format (i.e. indent) XML documents before applying path expressions to them? Your answer is appreciated, here are some tips: XML and XPath are case-sensitive. If an element in the input is called `CATALOG`, then `//catalog` will not find this element. `CATALOG` is the outermost element of the document, so you can start the expression with `/` instead of `//`: `/CATALOG`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller okay, thanks, but i tried that xpath in dev tools and it worked, but good to know. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: If your dev environment is a tool for HTML, then the path expressions might be case-insensitive because HTML is not case-sensitive. For a general XML dev tool, being insensitive to case is a serious bug that you should report.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I copied given code into txt file, renamed it to .html and opened it in Chrome so i guess cause of that it's not sensitive.

Comment: Here is a tool that I often use when answering XPath questions: http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php. Perhaps that's easier than your method?